# Mongoose find check null coalesce on nested object in an array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a model like this:

```
var organization = new Schema({
  things:[
    {a:{
      b:string
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

And I am trying to `findOne` with Mongoose like this:

```
let organization = await Organization.findOne({
  "things.a.b": "uniquestring",
});
```

But the problem is that `a` may be null.

I would like to do something like this:

```
let organization = await Organization.findOne({
  "things.a?.b": "uniquestring",
});
```

> Is there a way to check for null on this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but can't you do something like this. If you think your only issue is there may be some `null` objects

Assuming your object looks like this

```
[
  {
    "things": [
      {
        "a": {
          "b": "test"
        }
      },
      {
        "a": null
      },
      {
        "a": {
          "b": "abc"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then you can run this query

```
db.collection.find({
  things: {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "a.b": "test"
    }
  }
},
{
  "things.$": 1
})
```

You can check MongoDB playground [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8fZn-Z9WO__)